# Hibernate: Projection of a collection returns ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, partial, projection

I'm trying to get a partial object back using projection in hibernate, like this:

Movie class:

```
@Table(name = "Movies")
public class Movie extends Entity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "title")
private String title;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "Movie_Genre", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "movieId")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "genreId")})
private List<Genre> genres;
```

When the user then goes to htp://localhost:8080/api/movies?fields=genres this is called:

Movie DAO:

```
Criteria cr = getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Movie.class);
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
projectionList.add(Projections.property("genres"), "genres");
cr.setProjection(projectionList);
cr.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Movie.class));
return cr.list();
```

But this returns:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.getResultRow(CriteriaLoader.java:166)
```

Hibernate Query:

```
select this_.id as y0_ from Movies this_
```

Projections do not work when you want to project a collection...

Can somebody tell me what to do? How can this be fixed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't figure out what are you trying to query.

Comment: The movie class had id, title, genres,... But I only want to get genres. If I do this with title, it's OK. With genres I get this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: Still not clear: you need all movies that have some genre? Or all genres of a movie?

Comment: I need a list of movies where every movie has his own list of genres.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that for title you actually have a field in the Movies entity. For the collection this cannot work since the database table has no field "genres". Rather there is an entity called "Movie_Genre" that is actually having foreign key fields to Movies and Genres.

So on database level there is no field for "genres" such that the basically only the Exception is a bit misleading. The Exception is thrown in "applyLocks" in CriteriaLoader and as the database dialect could not find a column for "genres" there are actually no columns in the returned result.

Which exact version of Hibernate are you using?

Why are you using projections and not just an Restrictions.in?